# Filtering words in /usr/share/dict/words using grep (Linux)

Tags: linux, unix, command

Good day everybody, after searching the internet upside-down I couldnot find the answer to my question. Any kind of help is very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

I need to sort words in the file by the direction /usr/share/dict/words in the way so that every sorted word should begin with the letter sequence "on" and end with the letter sequence "in", it doesn't matter what is in the middle. (for example the word "**On**kochish**in**" ik its not an english word, whatever).

I tried the command "grep "^on\in$" /usr/share/dict/words", but it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
grep '^on.*in$' /usr/share/dict/words
awk '/^on.*in$/' /usr/share/dict/words
```